# azure webapp node default start script

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want an npm script to run after deployment in my azure webapp.

I assumed that `npm run start` would automatically be executed. However this does not seem to be the case. I already tried to leave the start script emtpy and the server still works. I also tried to run some random node file in the start script and this does not get executed. So I assume that azure does not run 
`npm run start` by default, but rather executes `node index.js`

How can I run npm scripts instead?

Comment: You could go to [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) of your web service and run the npm command.

Comment: The shell only runs node 0.11, but I need >8

Comment: You could get to App Setting add “WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION” and Value “8.9.4”

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to deploy a Node app on Azure, which be using a higher Node runtime version than the default one `0.11`.

I have answered it for your other similar question [azure webapp webjob node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771467/azure-webapp-webjob-node-version/54781448#54781448), the solution is set the value of `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` with the version number you want in Application settings tab of Azure portal, please see the figure below.

[image]

On Azure, you can not directly startup your Node app via `npm run start`, because IIS on Azure WebApp will help starting it up via `web.config` file in `site/wwwroot` path. So you need to create & configure a `web.config` file, please refer to the Kudu wiki page [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps) to know how to configure. Or you can directly use the sample one if the `server.js` file also is the default startup file of your app.

Comment: @Chris Any update? Could you mark it if my answer helps?

Comment: Hello Peter Pan, Chris!
I have a similar problem, but am using python dash (to emulate ReactJS).
Similar as Chris, I am wondering what is run by default. I feel like it is whatever React exposes as "app", thus I wrote into my `app.py`:
`app = app_dash.server`
But still, nothing happens. What do you use in *Application Settings > Runtime > Startup File*? Thanks!

Comment: @LionelTrebuchon Hi, you can create a new SO thread for your question with tag `azure` & `python`. To do so will helps other people with similar issue and obey the SO's rules. Then, I will find yours via these tags and try my best to help you.

Comment: Ok. I was unsure whether this question was maybe related. Thanks!

Comment: @LionelTrebuchon No matter, please post your question with `azure` & `python` tags, then I will see.