# azure webapp webjob node version

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-web-app-service

How can I define the node version that is used to run azure webjobs?

The server currently executes my code with v0.11 and fails since I use features that require node >8

The web app itself runs on node 8 just fine, but the version for webjobs seems to be independent of the webserver itself.

Answer (score 1):

On Azure WebApp, for Node.js runtime, there is a default version which be older that `0.10.40` or others like `0.11` as you said. If you want to change the default Node version for running your webjob, there are two ways below to configure it.

1. To set the value of `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` with the version number you want in `Application settings` tab of Azure portal. You can refer to my answer for the existing SO thread [Azure NodeJS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034084/azure-nodejs-version/54070657#54070657).

   [image]
2. To create a zip file as webjob which wrapped your Node JavaScript and a bootstrap file, please refer to the offical document [`Supported file types for scripts or programs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#acceptablefiles). For example, a WebJob zip file includes `index.js` and `run.bat` as below, you can set the `PATH` environment to add the Node runtime path supported by Azure (you can list all version of NodeJS on Azure by following my answer above) to make it works.

   index.js

   ```
   console.log(process.version)
   ```

   run.bat

   ```
   set PATH=D:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/8.11.1/;%PATH%
   node index.js
   ```

   [image]

   Then, following the below figure steps, you can add & run your webjob zip file and see the output result via `Logs`.

[image]

Here is my result in `Logs` when I set my Node runtime version `10.14.1` as below.

[image]

Comment: @Chris Any update? If my answer is helpful for you, could you mark it?