# How to tell azure to run node server.js

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, visual-studio-2017

i have angular 6 app running fine on azure too but i need to add a server.js file for some server variables i added server.js file on root like

**Server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();
const publicIp = require('public-ip');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
// Angular DIST output folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/projectname')));


app.get('/getip', (req, res) => {
  var ipcheck = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
  (async () => {
    console.log(await publicIp.v4());
    res.json({
      ip: await publicIp.v4(),
      ip2: req.headers['x-forwarded-for'],
      ip3: req.connection.remoteAddress,
      ip4: req.ip
    });

  })();
});
// Send all other requests to the Angular app
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/projectname/index.html'));
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/prjectname/index.html'));
});


//Set Port
const port = process.env.PORT || '3000';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on localhost:${port}`));
```

then i goto cmd and run node server.js it works great on localhost
but now i want to do same on azure server how to deploy it.
or how to tell azure always **run node server.js**

Comment: Do you want to deploy it on Azure WebApp? Or others like VM or Functions? Or you just want to know how to deploy it to Azure with a suitable service.

Comment: webapp i got publish setting too but don't know how to run it through nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just build your project **ng build --prod** then open project folder in dist folder in vs 17 then add

package.json

index.js

web.config

you can get these 3 files form [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) and you can edit index.js as per need i just need to add this

```
app.get('/getip', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
      ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(":")[0]
    });
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

this runs my app through nodejs.

when i call getip this gives me server ip and otherwise return angular index.html which handle all routing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have known how to create an Azure WebApp in Azure Portal or [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). Then, I see you developed your Node.js app in Visual Stodio 2017 and want to deploy it to Azure using the same tool, so I suggested you can refer to the NTVS wiki page [`Publish to Azure Website using Web Deploy`](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Publish-to-Azure-Website-using-Web-Deploy) to know how to do.

Next, there are four notes below you have to know first before deploying.

1. Please confirm the Node.js version in your created WebApp, the default version is `0.10+`. You can accessing the Kudo console of your webapp via the url `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` and command `node -v` to get it. You can set it in Azure CLI to run the command like `az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group <your ResourceGroup> --name <app_name> --settings WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=10.14.1` or follow the figure below in Azure portal. For more details about Node version on Azure WebApp, please refer to my answer for the SO thread [azure webapp webjob node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54771467/azure-webapp-webjob-node-version/54781448#54781448).

[image]

2. In your project, there must be a `Web.config` file to talk with IIS on Azure WebApp how to startup your Node app. The content of `Web.config` file is the same as the sample in the Kudu wiki page [`Using a custom web.config for Node apps`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps), you can directly copy it because your bootstrap js file name also is `server.js`.
3. The listening port on Azure WebApp is random assigned by environment, you can get it from the environment variable `HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT` which also will be got by `process.env.PORT`. So you will not do anything in your code for `port`.
4. Your Node app will be deployed into the path `home/site/wwwroot` of Azure WebApp which also can be accessed via Kudu console. Therefore, without any tools, you also can use Kudu console to deploy your app, just make the file structure in `wwwroot` as same as your project, which includes all js files and directories, `node_modules` and `web.config`.